# Cygwin: alias to Program Files (x86) directory

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

Using cygwin, I'm trying to create the following alias:

```
alias write="/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

When I execute the command to launch notepad++ directly, I have no issues.  But when I alias it and then try to call `write`, I get an error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I've also tried removing the quotes and escaping the spaces and parens:

```
alias write=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe
```

and got the same result.

I have a workaround where I place a symlink to the executable in my home folder and alias `write` to the symlink, but I'd prefer to have it aliased directly.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I'm trying to create the following alias

```
alias write="/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

Use the following command:

```
alias write='C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'
```

Notes:

- Change `\` to `/`
- Escape <kbd>space</kbd> , `(` and `)`
- Quote using `'`
- Use the normal path instead of `/cycgdrive/c/` (for a windows program not in the cygwin directory hierarchy)

Comment: This is due to the expand_aliases option of bash